# Issue with the commenting systems timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, comments

I'm having this weird issue with my comment code for my comment system. I put in a feature where you have to wait 10 seconds after each comment. It worked fine before but now that I changed the code a little i'm having an issue. When you comment, the error comes up even if it's the first comment you have posted which should be because the timer shouldn't even be active yet.

The full code is:

```
1    var h = 0,
2       i, j = 10;
3    $(".comment").click(function () {
4       if (h == 0) {
5           var a = $(this).attr("data-post"),
6               b = $(".comname-" + a).text(),
7               c = $(".combody-" + a).val();
8           if ($.trim(b) == "") {
9               alertBox("Missing Field", "Please Enter a Name to Comment.", "Close")
10          }
11          else if ($.trim(c) == "") {
12              alertBox("Missing Field", "Please Enter a Comment.", "Close")
13          }
14          else {
15              var d = true;
16              if (c.length > 54) {
17                  if ($$.string(c).count(" ") < 3) {
18                      d = false
19                  }
20              }
21              if (d == true) {
22                  $.post("post.php?action=comment", {
23                      id: a,
24                      name: b,
25                      com: c
26                  }, function (b) {
27                      var c = $$.string(b).found(/\[[0-9]\] => (.+)/g, 2);
28                      $(".no-" + a).hide();
29                      $(".comname-" + a + ", .combody-" + a).val("");
30                      $(".comholder-" + a).append('<div class="commenthold comment-' + c[3] + '"><span class="content-' + c[3] + '">' + c[1] + '</span> <br> <span class="name cname-' + c[3] + '">' + c[0] + '</span><span class="comment-timeago" style="float:right" title="' + c[2] + '"></span><img src="/img/edit.png" class="edit tip" title="Edit Comment" style="cursor:pointer" data-id="' + a + '" onclick="openEdit(' + c[3] + ')"/><img src="/img/edited.png" title="This comment has be edited 0 times" class="times-' + c[3] + '" style="display:none;cursor:pointer;width: 13px;  height: 13px;  position: absolute;  top: 0px;  right: -17px;"><div style="color:red;position:absolute;top:2px;right:4px;cursor:pointer" title="Delete Comment" data-id="' + a + '" onclick="delO(' + a + ',' + c[3] + ')" class="tip"><img class="width" src="/img/remove.png" /></div></div><br>');
31                      $(".tip").tipsy({
32                          gravity: "sw"
33                      });
34                      $(".comment-timeago").timeago();
35                      var d = parseInt($(".show-" + a).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")) + 1;
36                      $(".show-" + a).text(d + " Comment" + (d !== 1 ? "s" : ""))
37                  });
38                  h = 1;
39                  i = setTimeout(function () {
40                      h = 0
41                  }, j * 1e3);
42              }
43              else {
44                  alertBox("Error", "You must have at least 4 words considering the length of this comment.", "Close")
45              }
46          }
47      }
48      else {
49          clearTimeout(i);
50          i = setTimeout(function () {
51              h = 0
52          }, j * 1e3);
53          alertBox("Timer Warning", "Must wait " + j + " seconds before commenting again. Timer Reset.", "Close")
54      }
55    });
```

The weird part is that if I were to add an alert at the beginning before `if (h == 0)` then it works fine and it doesn't show the error box for the timer.

But if I put console.log logging what `h` equals it will log twice, meaning that it is running the code twice. Even though it only seems to run once with the alert.

The Console (firebug):

[image: The Console]

See?

### Code Explaination.

I know that just looking at code can make understanding the code a little hard. I wanna make it easier on you.

**Lines 1-2**: Variables for the Timer. `h` is the status, 0 = You can comment; 1 = Timer still isn't over. `i` is the variable the setTimeout will be stored in. `j` is the number of seconds before you can comment again.
**Line 4**: Start `if` to make sure that the timer is over.
**Lines 5-7**: Some more variables to get the Post Id (data-post), to the name of the person who commented (comnam), and to get the actual comment (combody)
**Lines 8-13**: Makes sure both the Name and the Comment has content in it.
**Line 15**: For another type of error.
**Lines 16-20**: If the comment is more than 55 characters then check if it has more than 3 words. If not `d` == false which will trigger an error.
**Line 27**: This variable contains a special function which uses a little RegExp to get all of the information from `b` (information from PHP such as the timestamp).
**Line 28**: Hide the "There are no comments yet! Be the First!" if there were no comments already.
**Line 29**: Clear the Name and Comment Field.
**Line 30**: Append the comment into the comment area.
**Lines 35-36**: Update the text that tells you how many comments there are.
**Lines 39-41**: Start Timer, after 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds) turn `h` back to 0 so you can continue commenting.
**Lines 50-52**: Reset Timer

I Don't really see what the issue is and why it is running the code twice. I have nothing in the code to run it again.

Thanks for any help and I hope I have made my issue clear enough for you.

Comment: NITPICK: What is with the cryptic variable names? a,b,c,d,h? Use real words so you know what they are! Use a [script](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) to change the names for you when you are ready to release.

Comment: instead of using a timeout, you can set a viraible with the actual timestamp when posting a comment. Then you only need to compare the the old timestamp and the new one when commenting again.

Comment: Do you really have all this code with ZERO comments in the code?  And, on top of that, you're using meaningless variable names like `a`, `b` and `c`.  Give all your variables a meaningful name.  Add explanatory comments to your code while you are writing it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys but I code how I like. I don't need comments because I know my codes from top to bottom. Even if I haven't seen it in month. I will get back into it. And I use cryptic variable names because its faster than writing out: "idForComments" for example. I would like you to know that I have fixed my problem myself.